# How to install guest addition in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, gcc, guest-additions

Today, i  installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on latest virtualbox. everything is fine except fullscreen. I tried to install guest addition by clicking on " Insert guest addition CD image ". At first , it said `gcc make perl` is not install on your Ubuntu. i checked the installation step of `gcc make perl`on Ask Ubuntu website and did the same.

But error occurred. i did it (guest addition) manually by the same step written on Ask Ubuntu website but didn't succeed. now , neither terminal-commands works nor "insert guest addition CD image " that is as a option of `Devices`. What to do now ? i am not pasting the error that comes after clicking `insert guest addition CD image` in `Devices` because after so many try, i can't paste. Help me.

Answer (score 1):

Is your host or guest Ubuntu 20.04 LTS? That is not clear from your question.

You might want to follow the [documentation on Virtualbox here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html). Assuming that your guest is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS:

1. Make sure that your *guest* is prepared for building external kernel modules. Refer to [this section of documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#mountingadditionsiso).
2. Insert the VirtualBox guest additions CD into your Linux guest.
3. Run the shell script on the virtual CD by `sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`